# After changed DOM iframe object to iframe, javascript start infinite loop

Tags: javascript, iframe

After changed DOM `iframe` object to `iframe`, JavaScript start infinite loop.

```
var i = 0;
document.onmousemove = (function () {
    if (i < 1) {
        i++;
        document.write('<iframe src=\"http://example.com\" height=200 width=200 align=\"left\"></iframe>');
    }
})
```

What I doing wrong?

Dom example http://jsfiddle.net/JkJNH/6/
This example http://jsfiddle.net/JkJNH/7/

Comment: Are you intending to create a new iframe evey time the mouse moves? If not, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you show us the difference to "DOM iframe object", please?

Comment: Do never use `document.write` after the DOM is loaded!!!